# Can I use Google Apps Script instead of Formulas for doing calculations on a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

1. Is Google Apps Script faster than FORMULAS for calculating `sum` or
   `sumif` in a spreadsheet which has around 10,000 rows?
2. How does FORMULA work?
3. I know Google Apps Script executes its code in the cloud, but is there any way for that to work client-side just like JavaScript?

Comment: Yes you can use Google Script instead of formulas.   For answer to the rest of your questions start [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) that's where we find them.

Comment: 1) no 2) how you want it to 3) no

Comment: Thank you @CodeCamper.
Is FORMULAS working in the client side?

Comment: @Yadhu Yes, and you can have desync issues as a result but refreshing the page will always bring you back to what everyone else sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is Google Apps Script faster than FORMULAS for calculating sum or
   sumif in a spreadsheet which has around 10000 rows?

   *No*
2. How does FORMULA work?

   *Client side, can cause desync issues but refreshing the page brings you back to what everyone else sees. So there is actually a server side and client side execution of these formulas to a certain extent*
3. I know Google Apps Script executes its code in the cloud, but is
   there any way for that to work client-side just like JavaScript?

   *No*